# How to store extra data to a swing checkbox?

Tags: java, swing, checkbox

It's easy to create a checkbox in swing, as:

```
JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox("hello")
```

The problem is I also want to associate some other values with this `checkbox`, e.g. another number, `99`

But I can't find any methods of a `JCheckBox` to do it, how to do it?

Comment: get/putClientProperty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 3.**

You really need to store alot of values.... extend it....

```
public class MySuperStoreAlotOfValuesCheckbox extends JCheckBox{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int theInt;
    ... all the values in the world...
    public MySuperStoreAlotOfValuesCheckbox(String text){
        super(text);
    }
    public MySuperStoreAlotOfValuesCheckbox(String text, int theInt){
        super(text);
        this.theInt = theInt;
    }
}
```

**Option 4** as suggested by @mKorbel in comment

```
checkbox.putClientProperty("myInt",99);
```

> The `clientProperty` dictionary is not intended to support large scale extensions to JComponent nor should be it considered an alternative to subclassing when designing a new component.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Using Map to associate checkbox with values.

```
Map<JCheckBox, Integer> map = new HashMap<JCheckBox, Integer>();
map.put(checkbox, 99);
int value = map.get(checkbox);
```

Option 2: Using [JCheckBox#setActionCommand(String cmd)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setActionCommand%28java.lang.String%29)

```
checkbox.setActionCommand("99");
int value = new Integer(checkbox.getActionCommand());
```